# Proving limit equals infinity using limit definition

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

How can I prove that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 5^-} \frac{1}{x-5}= - \infty$  **using the epsilon and delta method.** 
We know from the definition that: $\lim_{x \rightarrow 5^-} \frac{1}{x-5}= - \infty \Leftrightarrow $ For all $M>0$ there exists $\alpha > 0$, such that $0<|x-5|<\alpha \Rightarrow \frac{1}{x-5}< -M$.

I couldn't find alpha.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Work your way backwards. You want:
$$\frac{1}{x-5}<-M$$
which is equivalent to:
$$x-5 > -\frac{1}{M} \iff \color{blue}{5-x < \frac{1}{M}}$$
For the left-handed limit you're not looking at $x$-values satisfying $0<|x-5|<\alpha$ but (note that $|x-5|=5-x$ since $x<5$) you have: $0<\color{blue}{5-x<\alpha}$. Now spot a good choice for $\alpha$...

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response, but 1/(x-5) < -M => x-5 < (-1/M). ?

Comment: Also, I do not know how to procede to find alpha. Can you please help me.

Comment: Manipulating the inequality, this happens: $\tfrac{1}{a}<-b \iff a >-\tfrac{1}{b} \iff -a < \tfrac{1}{b}$. These are basic properties of the inequality. As for $\alpha$; carefully inspect the parts highlighted in blue...

Comment: Thank you very much. We take alpha= 1/M, hence  |x-5|<alpha => 5-x < 1/M => 1/(x-5) < -M which is what we want.

Comment: Correct; you're welcome.